# How to best implement a watchdog on a neverending task in C#?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I've got a service which, at its core, runs a few neverending loops by calling methods like:

```
public async Task DoStuffPeriodically(CancellationToken token);
```

They are invoked by calling:

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var stuffTask = DoStuffPeriodically(tokenSource.token);
```

Now, this will run forever, and only get stopped when, on a different method, we cancel the token and call `stuffTask.Wait()`. *Only then* do we get any exceptions that DoStuffPeriodically might have trown.

It is possible (but unlikely) that DoStuffPeriodically actually throws, which means the loop I'm counting on is no longer running. I was planning on monitoring it by having a loop in the main thread that periodically checks `stuffTask.IsFaulted` and throws an exception (which will force the service to reboot).

Is there a better way to do this? I wouldn't like to poll the Task state if there's anyway to get a callback from it that I'm unaware of.

Thanks!

Comment: Your use case seems more similar to a `Timer` than to a single thread spinning in the background. Another good option is to use a library which is specifically designed for this kind of tasks, like [Quartz.net](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet) or [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler). Both options have more robust exception handling, and will not stop your periodic work if an exception occurs.

Comment: @Miquel just came to that thread for some reason. We widely used `Timer` for that scenario, which kinda goes against most usage of async/await- however it catches errors properly and gives better guarantees. Greetings from Germany old friend ;-)

Comment: @ThomasJungblut we've gone witk Kapol's idea and used ContinueWith, seems to be working well so far! Also, really good to hear from you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Task.ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194741.aspx), passing `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` to the `continuationOptions` parameter. This will trigger the callback only when the antecedent threw an unhandled exception. In this callback you can set some flag or throw an exception.

```
stuffTask.ContinueWith(t => { throw new Exception(); },
    null, 
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Comment: Oh, brilliant! I hadn't thought of that at all. Thanks!